# Class changing based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onOXg.png)

This is what I am trying to achieve, class of the status would changed based on data coming.
My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cls = 'label-info';
    if(data-value == 'Progress'){
        cls = 'label-warning';
    }
    else(data-value == 'New'){
        cls = 'label-success';
    }
    $('#label').addClass(cos);
});
```

My JS:

My Html:

```
<span id="label" class="label label-sm " data-value = "{{ account.status }}"> {{ account.status }} </span>
```

Comment: please, share console logs

Comment: http://codepen.io/aihowes/pen/bZRxWr

Answer (score 0):

Change your class variable name

```
$('#label').addClass(cls);
```